# Facts and dimensions: dynamic dimensions

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, fact

(Appreciate this post is perhaps too high level or philosophical for SO, I'm in the schema planning phase and seeking some guidance)

After some difficulty working with a clone of our production database for analytics, I am attempting to define a events fact table along with some dimensions tables in order to make analytics work simpler.

The block I've hit in my planning is this. We have different categories of event with different dimensions needed to describe them. E.g. suppose we have 'account settings' event category as well as 'Gallery' events.

In a fact table I might have a field eventCategory and eventName with example values from above such as:

```
'EventCategory': 'Account Settings'
'EventName': 'Update Card Billing Details'
```

Or:

```
'EventCategory': 'Gallery'
'EventName': 'Create New Gallery'
```

In each case I want to use a different collection of dimensions to describe them. E.g. for Gallery events we want to know 'template', 'count of images', 'gallery category e.g. fruits'. We have no need for these details with account settings events, which have their own distinct set of dimensions to describe them.

Via the textbook examples I find online, I would have a dimensions table for Gallery events and a dimensions table for Account Settings events.

The mental block I have is that these dimensions are dynamic not static. I want to record in the fact table the value of these dimensions at the time of the event not 'now'. For example, a user can either be in trial or a paid user. If I had a dimension table 'user' their status might currently be 'paid' but at the time of some previous gallery event they may have been in trial.

What is the 'right' way to handle this:

- Multiple facts tables, one for Gallery events and one for Account Settings events?
- Use json in a new field in the main facts table e.g. 'EventDetail' which contains what would otherwise go in a dimension table except by using json we know the values of the dimensions at the time of the event as opposed to whatever those values are now?
- I could have a sparse facts table. I would include fields for each dimension across all categories and these would be null where not applicable

Given that the dimensions I use to describe an event are dynamic, what is the 'right' way to construct a fact table for analytics? The way I see it just now the dimensions tables would have to be facts themselves to capture the changing values of these attributes over time.

Comment: how did you end up solving this? I have a situation somewhat similar in which I need to store business metrics with user defined (unknown) dimensions. Anything you could share would be great. Also posted here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560317/dealing-with-dynamic-dimensions-for-metrics-data-analytics), but nothing so far.

Comment: @lowercase00 ended up using json field as a stand in for a separate dimension table. We captured the event details 'at the time of the event' in a json object. It 'works' for our needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a dimension to any SQL table is always done the same way, by adding a column.

In any kind of history, there is no "now".  Every status has a time period: a beginning and ending.  I usually name those columns `AsOf` and `Until`, because begin/end show up a lot as SQL keywords, making the column names harder to scan for.  Usually, only `AsOf` is needed, because you can self-join the table to find succeeding periods, and use NULL to represent 'now' (where "now" means, *as of the time the query is executed*).

> 'user' their status might currently be 'paid' but at the time of some previous gallery event they may have been in trial.

Right, so the user's status isn't just paid/trial.  It's *paid* or *trial* starting AsOf some date, until a later AsOf date for the same user.

It's hard to be more helpful.  There's a bit of jargon in your question, and it's couched in domain-specific terms.  I hope by attaching a date/time to every status, you can see your way out of the forest.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense, using an 'AsOf' timestamp. What do you think about using a json field instead to capture e.g. gallery dimensions at a point in time? Perhaps it's a 'cutting corners' approach? My goals here are simplicity and convenience of data retreival.

Comment: I think you will discover that JSON, as Fabian Pascal likes to say, adds complexity without power.  Anything you can express in JSON can be expressed using SQL tables, and by using only tables, you simplify the problem because the data have only one representation.

Comment: The one hassle in any kind of work like this that's impossible to avoid is overlapping time periods.  You have to build AsOf-Until pairs for two entities, and then join them `where a.AsOf between B.AsOf and B.Until or b.AsOf between a.AsOf and a.Until`.  It's awkward to express and confusing to think about, but there's no way around it.  There's no technical simplification, and it's unavoidable.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden I have a fairly similar situation (posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560317/dealing-with-dynamic-dimensions-for-metrics-data-analytics), and wondering if the suggestion would be the same (adding columns and making things more static), would be great to have any inputs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**(A) Managing temporal data in postgres**

Temporal data is a quite usual need in many kinds of business applications, but it is not a "built-in" feature in postgres, nor in many other RDBMS.

As stated by @James K. Lowden, you can use some `AsOf` and `Until` columns of type `timestamp` with or without time zone, or you can use instead a single column of type `tsrange` or `tstzrange`, ie a range of timestamps, and which will offer you some nice built-in functions, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html).

In order to avoid overlaps between timestamp ranges associated to different events for the same data, you can implement a business logic with trigger functions.
For instance for the same user, you can implement the following trigger function so that the range r1 associated to the status 'in trial' and the range r2 associated to the status 'paid' are automatically set up when the corresponding rows are inserted in the `user` table, and the ranges of the existing rows for the same user are updated accordingly :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert_user ()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
-- update all the existing rows (ie status) for the same user_id whose valid_ranges are valid as of now
  UPDATE user
     SET valid_range = tstzrange(lower(valid_range), Now())
   WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id
     AND valid_range @> Now() ;
-- set up the valid_range for the new row (ie the new status)
  NEW.valid_range = tstzrange(Now(), NULL) ;
END ;
$$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER before_insert_user BEFORE INSERT ON user
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION before_insert_user () ;
```

**(B) Managing different dimensions for different categpories**

As already discussed, `json` can be a solution to store various dimensions in the same column.

An other solution could be the table [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html) with some interesting functionalities :

```
CREATE TABLE Event
( EventCategory varchar
, EventName varchar
, ValidityRange tstzrange
, primary key (EventCategory , EventName, ValidityRange )
) ;

CREATE TABLE user
( status varchar
) INHERITS Event ;

CREATE TABLE Gallery
( template varchar
, "count of images" integer
, "gallery category e.g. fruits" varchar
)  INHERITS Event ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A fact table needs to have its grain defined; if facts don’t match that grain they can’t be stored in that fact table => if you have facts with different sets if dimensions then you need to use different fact tables.

Regarding the values in a dimension changing, you need to read up on Slowly Changing Dimensions